# Smallest possible baudrate for i2c?

Tags: i2c

I set it to 1200

```
$ cat /boot/config.txt
[...]
dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm=on_baudrate=1200
```

but

```
$ cat /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/baudrate
3814
```

Is this the minimum? Can I somehow go below that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The I2C hardware uses the core 250MHz clock in setting the bit rate.  The bit rate is set by a divide down of the core clock.  The divider is a 16 bit quantity and therefore the maximum divider is 65536.  250M/65536=3814.

[Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) page 34.

You have at least a couple of options.

- Underclock to lower the core clock speed
- bit bang I2C

Comment: +1 But to be picky: the limit to a 16-bit value is 65535 (2^16 **- 1**).

Comment: @goldilocks But to be irritating, if you use a divider of 0 a divider of 65536 is used!

Comment: I figured there might be some logic like that ;)